# C: Trying to insert a struct into a struct array

Tags: c, pointers

in my code I have student profiles with name, age, and GPA. I also have an array with each profile. I'm trying to create an insert function that inserts another student profile into the array and display an error if the index is not valid. I'm trying to do so by moving adding another space in the array for the new student, then moving over the places of students occupying the wrong space by one space to the right.

Ex. If I want to put a student in index 2, the function would move the student occupying that space to 3, and the student in 3 would be moved to space 4.

Here's what I have so far, but I'm getting an error on `array[i+1] = i`saying "incompatible types when assigning to type Student from type type int." I tried changing i to type Student, I got several more errors all over the loop saying that it was an invalid initializer and that I couldn't use >=, and that i was the "wrong type to decrement

Comment: That's an interesting indentation style

Comment: If the array is full of students - why are you assigning an integer?

Comment: `array[i+1] = i` <--- typo? `array[i+1] = array[i]`? Indeed, `int` is not `Student`, as the error says.

Comment: @Robert Andrzejuk I used int because size and index are of type int and I'm just trying to change the place in the array.

Comment: @Bepis Kid: Asteroids With Wings is right. Please, reformulate your question - so that you can get help. In advance: You can not change a position in an array by "array[i+1] = i". An assignment to array[i+1] can only set the element at position i+1.

Comment: where is the code?

Comment: Please do not vandalise your question. Work was put in by others to help you and the goal of this site is for that work to remain available to future visitors.

Answer (score 1):

For starters it is unclear why the parameter `index` has the signed type `int` instead of the unsigned type `size_t`. The unsigned type allows to avoid this redundant check

```
if (index < 0 || index > *size) {
    ^^^^^^^^^
```

Also if the value of `index` is greater than the current value of `*size` then it is enough just to append the passed item to the array.

So in general this check

```
if (index < 0 || index > *size) {
```

is redundant.

The function declaration is too complicated. There is no need to return pointer to the first element of the passed array. The function declaration will look more simpler if to write it like

```
size_t insert( Student a[], size_t n, size_t i, const Student *student );
```

That is the function returns the new size of the updated array.

This statement

```
array[i+1] = i;
```

does not make any sense because the left operand has the type Student while the right operand has the type int. Moreover it has a logical error because instead of the index `i + 1` you have to use the index `i`.

And instead of the manually written loop you could use the standard C function `memmove`.

Here is a demonstrative program that shows how the function can be defined.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX_LEN 10

typedef struct Student
{
    char name[MAX_LEN];
    unsigned int age;
} Student;

size_t insert( Student a[], size_t n, size_t i, const Student *student )
{
    if ( n < i ) i = n;
    
    if ( i < n )
    {
        memmove( a + i + 1, a + i, ( n - i ) * ( sizeof( Student ) ) );
    }
    
    a[i] = *student;
    
    return ++n;
}
   
int main(void) 
{
    enum { N = 10 };
    Student a[N] = { 0 };
    
    Student student = { "A", 20 };
    
    size_t n = insert( a, 0, 0, &student );
    
    for ( size_t i = 0; i < n; i++ )
    {
        printf( "{ %s, %u } ", a[i].name, a[i].age );
    }
    putchar( '\n' );
    
    strcpy( student.name, "B" );
    ++student.age;
    
    n = insert( a, n, 0, &student );
    
    for ( size_t i = 0; i < n; i++ )
    {
        printf( "{ %s, %u } ", a[i].name, a[i].age );
    }
    putchar( '\n' );
    
    strcpy( student.name, "C" );
    ++student.age;
    
    n = insert( a, n, 2, &student );
    
    for ( size_t i = 0; i < n; i++ )
    {
        printf( "{ %s, %u } ", a[i].name, a[i].age );
    }
    putchar( '\n' );
    
    strcpy( student.name, "E" );
    ++student.age;
    n = insert( a, n, 1, &student );
    
    for ( size_t i = 0; i < n; i++ )
    {
        printf( "{ %s, %u } ", a[i].name, a[i].age );
    }
    putchar( '\n' );
    
    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
{ A, 20 } 
{ B, 21 } { A, 20 } 
{ B, 21 } { A, 20 } { C, 22 } 
{ B, 21 } { E, 23 } { A, 20 } { C, 22 }
```

Answer (score -2):

1. The used indentation style makes it difficult to easily see if the parenthesis are correctly closed. Please use an automatic formatter, example: clang-format
2. Your function is not very safe. It should take another parameter `max_size` so the assigned memory is known
3. If a return is used in `if` branch, the `else` branch does not have to be explicitly declared.
4. A `for` loop already has a condition, if the only functionality in the loop is an `if`, it can be hoisted up into that condition.
5. To move students from a place in an array a "copy" of the student has to be made to the new location - not just it's index.

Fixed:

```
Student* insert(Student* array, int max_size, int* size, int index, Student s)
{
    //error message and return NULL if space is - or > array size
    if (index < 0 || index > *size || *size + 1 > max_size)
    {
        printf("ERROR\n");
        array = NULL;
        return array;
    }

    for (int i = *size; i > index && i > 0; --i)
    {
        //move students at index or > over to make open space
        array[i] = array[i - 1];
    }

    //put new student in correct location
    array[index] = s;

    *size += 1;
    
    return array;
}
```